# AS3 AIR mobile app input validation

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have multiple input fields in a mobile (iOS and Android) app that I would like to validate.

Some I would only like numbers, others can't contain special characters and some need to be doubles.

Does anyone know any classes that can handle this and manage an error message?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with restrict property of TextInput class.

```
<s:TextInput id="txtOnlyNumbers" restrict="[0-9]" maxChars="9" /> here no error message will come we are preventing from user typ
```

(OR)

```
           var regOnlyNumbers:RegExp = /[0-9]/g;
            var numbers:String = "12345";
            Alert.show("Is Contains only Numbers " + regOnlyNumbers.test(numbers));

            var regIsSpecialChars:RegExp = /\W/g;
            var special:String = "12345";
            Alert.show("Is Contains special char " +regIsSpecialChars.test(special));

            var regIsSpecialChars:RegExp = /\W/g;
            var special:String = "123@45";
            Alert.show("Is Contains special char " +regIsSpecialChars.test(special));
```

Your set TextInput errorString property like

```
txtUserName.errorString = "It Contains interger";
```

It will show red border around textinput visual object and show will show when mouse over the textinput.

Do like

```
var regIsSpecialChars:RegExp = /\W/g;
if(regIsSpecialChars.test(txtUserName.text))
{
  txtUserName.errorString = "User Name having some special character(s)";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out when I can and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

ANOTHER APPROACH Please alter for your need

```
package
{
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.utils.StringUtil;
import mx.validators.StringValidator;

public class CommonValidator
{       

    public function CommonValidator()
    {

    }

    public static function accountNumberValidator(src:Object):Boolean
    {
        var regOnlyNumbers:RegExp = /[0-9]/g;
        var numbers:String = src.text;

       if(!regOnlyNumbers.test(numbers))
       {
         src.errorString = "It only allow numbers";     
       }

       return StringUtil.trim(src.errorString).length == 0;
    }

    public static function passwordValidator(src:Object):Boolean
    {
        var regIsSpecialChars:RegExp = /\W/g;
        var special:String = src.text;

        if(regIsSpecialChars.test(special))
        {
            src.errorString = "It contains special chars";              
        }

        return StringUtil.trim(src.errorString).length == 0;
    }

    public static function validateAll_ArrCollection(validationArr:ArrayCollection):Boolean
    {
        var arrFailure:Array = [];
        var isValid:Boolean = false;            

        for(var iIndex:int = 0;iIndex < validationArr.length;iIndex++)      
        {
            isValid = CommonValidator[validationArr.getItemAt(iIndex).methodName](validationArr.getItemAt(iIndex).srcObject);   

            if(isValid == false)
                arrFailure.push(isValid);
        }       

        return arrFailure.length == 0;

    }
}
```

}

Usage

```
    var arrColl:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    arrColl.addItem({methodName:"accountNumberValidator", srcObject:txtUserName});
    arrColl.addItem({methodName:"passwordValidator", srcObject:txtPassword});
    if(CommonValidator.validateAll_ArrCollection(arrColl))
{
trace("All fields are valid");
}
else {
trace("Fields are invalid");}
```